# Variable does not work outside of function

Tags: javascript

I have a function that loads a JSON file and gives it to a variable called articles. When i log articles inside of the function, it shows my json file, but when i log it outside of my function it doesn't show anything at all

I have tried to use let and var before articles inside of the function but that doesn't seem to work

```
var articles = ""
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
    articles = xmlhttp.responseText;
    console.log(articles);
  }
};
console.log(articles);
console.log(xmlhttp);
xmlhttp.open("GET","articles.json",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

I want to be able to call my json file outside of my function by using articles, so that i don't have ot type xml.responseText each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, JavaScript does not synchronously wait for I/O operations to finish (network call in this case).

What this means is that when you log articles "outside of the function", the articles variable has not yet been set (the http request has not been completed).

Why are you hoping to have access to articles globally?

You could optionally pass your articles into a processing method after the http request has responded like so:

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
    var articles = xmlhttp.responseText;
    processArticles(articles)
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET","articles.json",true);
xmlhttp.send();

function processArticles(articles) {
  // Do something with articles here
}
```

Comment: I need the articles to be asigned to my json file is because i have another function after this one that makes an html table using my variable articles. Would it be possible to simple wrap my function that makes the table in the processArticles one you made?

Comment: Yes, you should have the logic for creating the table inside the `processArticles` method.